# Performance of Java Programs reading from Files - or reading from Mainframe Db2 Tables

Tags: java, db2

What is efficient in terms of Performance  and CPU -  Java batch Programs reading from Files - or reading from Mainframe Db2 Tables.

1) Reading from File == Process using java db2 program and the program read files also  ==> O/P File
2) Move the files to Db2 staging tables  ==> Process using java db2 program (no files)  ==> Move  the data from Db2 Staging table to Files

Which one is recommended and why ?.  Our understanding here is Java program reading from Sequential file is inefficient .  Please advise

Comment: The only major reason to load the files into the database would be if doing so gained you some specific processing ability - mostly, if the **language** had a feature you wouldn't gain otherwise.  (In theory, SQL - and thus processing on the db - would allow easier parallel processing, but requires a decent amount of setup to enable it; indices and so forth)  However, if you're planning on grabbing individual rows from the db and processing them individually, that's going to be a major performance penalty.  What sort of processing are you trying to do?

Comment: It is for Batch processing , instead of reading from flat file + db2 tables,  move all the files to db2 tables and hence the application need not to read from flat files

Comment: Wait, so you already have _some_ data in db2?  If you only have a few "source" rows from your flat files, I'd probably still just read from them/write to them, _provided that any large set from the database is aggregated there, and not in your Java program_.  If you need to process a large set of "source" rows (10K-1M+), you're likely to be far better off if you bulk-load it into the database and use SQL to process it there.

Answer (score 0):

> > Our understanding here is Java program reading from Sequential file is inefficient .

Aren't you going to read from database tables sequentially or sequentially load data from files into database?
If your files are local and database is on remote server then network roundtrips may also influence overall performance.
And in case of file IO type of disks (HDD/SSD) will have significant impact.
You just need to write PoC for both cases and carefully measure results under approximate loads. But from your question option with reading from will simply has less steps.

Comment: All major RDBMSs have bulk load/export utilities, which will do far better than a naïve "sequential" load would.

Comment: We read the records sequentially from the table  , same way as files.  but many files will be in a same table for different batch proecessing and uniquly identified by the key.  Worried about locking concern too.